# Is it possible to cal IdentityServer4 API to issue a token?

Tags: identityserver4

When I host Identity Server in my Service it exposes '/connect/token' endpoint which I can call with `IdentityModel` library.

Is it possible to access IS4 services directly?

Something like this:

`someIS4Service.IssueTokenAsync(subj, claims, ...other params...)`
where `someIS4Service` is simply injected with ASP.NET Core DI.

So created tokens are automatically persisted in DB, as they would if endpoint were accessed?

Comment: It's not possible out of the box. And issued tokens are not necessarily persisted, unless its a refresh token or a reference token.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Yes, I meant refresh tokens.

Comment: Yeah i thought so, my point still stands though - it's not possible, IDS4 was designed to work over internet protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Technically that's possible, but with a bit more work than a simple call: you may look for [`ITokenResponseGenerator`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/ResponseHandling/ITokenResponseGenerator.cs) in the DI and invoke the [`ProcessAsync`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/0c097eef57e98aec36eb34727acea2c998415687/src/IdentityServer4/src/ResponseHandling/Default/TokenResponseGenerator.cs#L79) method, but you have to provide a pre-processed `TokenRequestValidationResult`.

As a *service* you most likely do not need that. You might need to create an *access token* to perform a *service-to-service* call and that's easy to do with [IdentityServerTools](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/tools.html) (no persistence, no session handling, just an easy approach to jwt generation).